# What video resolution and format is most suitable for ios apps?

Tags: ios, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I would like to play full-screen videos as a background in one of my apps. The problem is that videos take up a lot of space. What resolution and format is most suitable for ios apps? The main criteria are 
file size &
loading time.

Comment: I am using Dimensions : 540 × 960
Codecs : H.264
Duration : 00:11
Format : MPEG-4 movie
Size : 4.4 Mb
And works well for iPhone 4 to iPhone 6

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The supported video types are mentioned at the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/hls_authoring_specification_for_apple_devices):

> iPhone OS provides support for full-screen video playback through the Media Player framework (MediaPlayer.framework). This framework supports the playback of movie files with the .mov, .mp4, .m4v, and .3gp filename extensions and using the following compression standards:
>
> - H.264 video, up to 1.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Low-Complexity version of the H.264 Baseline Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats
> - H.264 video, up to 768 Kbps, 320 by 240 pixels, 30 frames per second, Baseline Profile up to Level 1.3 with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats
> - MPEG-4 video, up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Simple Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats
> - Numerous audio formats, including the ones listed in “Audio Technologies”

Best video formats for iPhone 6/6+, [link](http://www.macxdvd.com/mac-dvd-video-converter-how-to/iphone-6-video-audio-formats-supported.htm):

> 1. H.264 video up to 1080p, 60 frames per second, High Profile level 4.2/4.1 with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats;
> 2. MPEG-4 video up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Simple Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps per channel, 48kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats;
> 3. Motion JPEG (M-JPEG) up to 35 Mbps, 1280 by 720 pixels, 30 frames per second, audio in ulaw, PCM stereo audio in .avi file format.

Comment: Are you using the video which has been recorded by your application? It's possible to manage the quality of the video before it has been recorded, read about video presets, it will help you to manage the video quality, its size and resolution as well.

Comment: Thank you! No, I will add a custom one. Hmm.. 640 by 480 pixels is pretty bad quality. on ihone 6s+ that wouldn't look good.

Comment: The question was what are the preferred formats, not supported formats, like Apple has some preferred audio formats mentioned https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW28

Comment: current - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/hls_authoring_specification_for_apple_devices